# Discord.js Cannot Read property 'run' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im created a bot for discord using Discord.js, and every time I try to run my Bal command through my command handler it rejects it with the error ***Cannot read property 'run' of undefined***

here is my code for **Index.js**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const db = require("@replit/database")

const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = process.env.TOKEN;

const keep_alive = require('./keep_alive.js')

const PREFIX = "orb ";

const fs = require('fs');

const activities_list = [
    "orb help.", 
    `${client.guilds.cache.size} servers!`,
    "n 3^o7 !"
];

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const ecocommandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./ecocommands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of ecocommandFiles){
    const command = require(`./ecocommands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("Orbitus online");
    setInterval(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1);
        client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index], { type: 'WATCHING' });
    }, 30000);
});

//Command Handler\\
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if(command === 'bal'){
        client.commands.get('bal').run(message, args, Discord);
    }
});


client.login(token);
```

And here is my code for **Bal.js**

```js
module.exports.run = async (message, args, Discord) => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX))return;  

  let user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.author;

  let bal = db.fetch(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`)

  if (bal === null) bal = 0;

  let bank = await db.fetch(`bank_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`)
  if (bank === null) bank = 0;

  let moneyEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor("#FFFFFF")
  .setDescription(`**${user}'s Balance**\n\nPocket: ${bal}\nBank: ${bank}`);
  message.channel.send(moneyEmbed)
};
```

I really need help because I want to continue development on my bot.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

so uuh , i think you should follow the official guide:

> https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/

your's seems bit similar but maybe got from yt (etc)

anyway the issue is
you dont export `name` from `Bal.js` only run (`function`)

`module.exports.run = .....`

and as name is `undefined`
your here setting undefined as the key with your run function to `client.commands` (`collection`)

```
for(const file of ecocommandFiles){
    const command = require(`./ecocommands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
                          ^^^^^^^^

}
```

now only key in the `client.commands` collection is undefined

`client.commands.get('bal')` this will come undefined as there is not command called bal in your collection (only undefined)

what you could do is add
`module.exports.name = 'bal'` into bal.js

every command from now on should have this (if you decide to use this way)

> Again I would suggest you read the discord.js official guide as it very beginner friendly and has a command handler and dynamic command handling tutorials with additional features, I will leave the links down below if you need them :)

**Links**

Official-docs: [Click-here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

official guide (`this is the official guide for beginners with d.js`): [Click-here](https://discordjs.guide/)

Command-Handling (guide): [Click-here](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/)

Dynamic-Command-Handling(guide) : [Click-here](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#dynamically-executing-commands)

Additional-Features) (guide): [Click-here](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html)

**Other guides:**

Event handling (from the same official guide): [Click-here](https://discordjs.guide/event-handling/#individual-event-files)

An-idiots-Guide (`use jointly with the official guide`): [Click-here](https://anidiots.guide/)